# ERROR WHILE CREATING A VIEW USING IF CONDITION

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am creating a stored procedure as below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSUPPLIERSOA]
@CHARTNUMBER1 INT = NULL,
@CHARTNUMBER2 INT = NULL,
@ASONDATE DATETIME = NULL
AS
BEGIN
IF OBJECT_id('vwSUPPLIERSOA') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP VIEW vwSUPPLIERSOA
GO
CREATE VIEW vwSUPPLIERSOA AS
    SELECT GLJRNDTL.JOURNALCODE, GLJRNDTL.JOURNALNUM, GLJRNDTL.POSTEDDATE,         APINVHED.CHARACTER01, APINVHED.INVOICENUM, APINVHED.INVOICEDATE, APINVHED.DUEDATE,     
    GLJRNDTL.TRANSAMT, APINVHED.PAYAMOUNTS, APINVHED.DOCPAYAMOUNTS, APINVHED.INVOICEBAL, APINVHED.DOCINVOICEBAL, APINVHED.CURRENCYCODE, APINVHED.EXCHANGERATE
FROM GLJRNDTL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN APINVHED
ON  APINVHED.INVOICENUM = GLJRNDTL.APINVOICENUM
WHERE GLJRNDTL.GLCHART BETWEEN @CHARTNUMBER1 AND @CHARTNUMBER2 AND   GLJRNDTL.POSTEDDATE < @ASONDATE


END
```

I GET THE ERROR MESSAGE AS BELOW

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spSUPPLIERSOA, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near 'vwSUPPLIERSOA'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure vwSUPPLIERSOA, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@CHARTNUMBER1".
```

Please let me know where I am getting wrong.

Comment: Creating a view from within a stored procedure would have to use dynamic SQL. Are you sure you need to do this - is there a reason you have the procedure changing the view definition? Would you not be better served by having e.g. a table-valued function that can directly accept the required parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables in a view. So what I can see you have these options:

You are anyway droping the view if it already there. Then I can't really see a point of the view. So you can do this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSUPPLIERSOA]
@CHARTNUMBER1 INT = NULL,
@CHARTNUMBER2 INT = NULL,
@ASONDATE DATETIME = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
     GLJRNDTL.JOURNALCODE, GLJRNDTL.JOURNALNUM, 
     GLJRNDTL.POSTEDDATE, APINVHED.CHARACTER01, 
     APINVHED.INVOICENUM, APINVHED.INVOICEDATE, APINVHED.DUEDATE,     
     GLJRNDTL.TRANSAMT, APINVHED.PAYAMOUNTS, APINVHED.DOCPAYAMOUNTS,
     APINVHED.INVOICEBAL, APINVHED.DOCINVOICEBAL, APINVHED.CURRENCYCODE,
     APINVHED.EXCHANGERATE
FROM GLJRNDTL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN APINVHED
ON  APINVHED.INVOICENUM = GLJRNDTL.APINVOICENUM
WHERE GLJRNDTL.GLCHART BETWEEN @CHARTNUMBER1 
AND @CHARTNUMBER2 AND   GLJRNDTL.POSTEDDATE < @ASONDATE
END
```

Alternative you can create a table value function that you later can select from. Like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION funcSUPPLIERSOA
(
    @CHARTNUMBER1 INT,
    @CHARTNUMBER2 INT,
    @ASONDATE DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT 
     GLJRNDTL.JOURNALCODE, GLJRNDTL.JOURNALNUM, 
     GLJRNDTL.POSTEDDATE, APINVHED.CHARACTER01, 
     APINVHED.INVOICENUM, APINVHED.INVOICEDATE, APINVHED.DUEDATE,     
     GLJRNDTL.TRANSAMT, APINVHED.PAYAMOUNTS, APINVHED.DOCPAYAMOUNTS, 
     APINVHED.INVOICEBAL, APINVHED.DOCINVOICEBAL, APINVHED.CURRENCYCODE, 
     APINVHED.EXCHANGERATE
FROM GLJRNDTL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN APINVHED
ON  APINVHED.INVOICENUM = GLJRNDTL.APINVOICENUM
WHERE GLJRNDTL.GLCHART BETWEEN @CHARTNUMBER1 AND @CHARTNUMBER2 
AND   GLJRNDTL.POSTEDDATE < @ASONDATE
```

Then select from it like this with a store procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSUPPLIERSOA]
@CHARTNUMBER1 INT = NULL,
@CHARTNUMBER2 INT = NULL,
@ASONDATE DATETIME = NULL
AS
SELECT * FROM funcSUPPLIERSOA(@CHARTNUMBER1,@CHARTNUMBER2,@ASONDATE) AS tbl
```